# Since Synchronous machines are constant speed machines how are their speeds varying with variation in load?

Tags: torque, electrical-engineering

I understand that the power output depends on torque angle. So how does an increase in torque angle cause the rotor speed to reduce? Aren't the [synchronous machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor) supposed to be running at constant speed?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to give a brief description of a "synchronous machine" (synchronous motor?) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

A synchronous motor will not reduce in speed with increasing load until a certain load is reached.  It will continue to run at the same speed, phased to the AC power line, until the torque demand exceeds what it can produce in that mode.  At zero load, the voltage and current are out of phase, so the average electrical consumption is zero.  As the load increases, the voltage and current shift phase so the input power increases.  You cannot draw any more power than to have the voltage and current in perfect phase, when the power is $\frac 12V_{max}I_{max}$